# How to remove a Recent Item in the Windows 10 Search Box

Tags: windows-10

When you click on the Microsoft Window 10's search box it shows the most recent items on a Window that popups (as shown in image 1 below). As shown in the image, you could then  hover over an item and click the `X` button to remove that item. Until very recently this feature was working, but all of a sudden the `X` button is gone (as shown in image 2 below) and I don't see any option to remove a recent item from that box. Question: What may be missing here and how can we remove a recent item from the search box popup window (shown in image 2)?

Remark: I am using latest version `20H2` of `Windows 10 - Pro`.

[image]

**Now, no X button to remove an item here**: There is no Right Click option either. The `Manage in Timeline` link - shown below - also does not give you a choice to remove a specific item.

[image]

**UPDATE**

To respond to the post from `@John`, I am also including this image that still not showing the `X` button even when you hover over the file. Morover, if you click on the file then (as it should) it just opens the file.

When I hover over the `Test1.rtf` file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X to delete an item is still there  (Screen shot below). You may need to click or hover on the item to see the X.  This is evident in the screen shot.  Also try restarting to check

If for sure the X is not there, try:

1. Updating the V21H1 (may be an optional update - check and see).
2. Run DISM and SFC

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

3. Then make a new test Windows User Account (User Profile), log in, try search a couple of times and see if the search history can be deleted.
4. If none of the above fixes the issue, then try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  If the user account is OK, use the Repair option to Keep Everything. That way, nothing is lost.

[image]

Comment: To answer your inquiry, I have just added an **UPDATE** section. I will try your other suggestions since it seems there is something wrong with my system only - as until probably yesterday or so,  it was doing exactly what your screen is showing before

Comment: Try my suggestions to see if they work. Also try a new, test Windows User Account. Certainly test in a new Windows Account. After that (if no) then you may need to try a repair install.

Comment: Or, I just noticed that in snaps shots 2 and 3 in my post are showing the files (and not the programs)  and hence therefore there is no  `X` option to remove the file. But it itself is strange that the search box is showing recently open files, because I thought it only shows recently open programs. Maybe time to repair  the install.

Comment: Search shows programs and files. I added the step for a Repair.

Comment: It started working fine next day. But I find your post very informative and will use your suggestions if issue popups again. It's only a week old new computer and maybe it's trying to adjust itself. But I'll keep an eye on it. It's is brand new Evoo laptop with EVOO 15.6" FHD Ultra Thin Intel Cor i7 8GB Memory, 256GB SSD. Came with Windows 10 home. I upgraded it to Professional editiion.

Comment: Thank you for the update.